# Does anyone know of a bank or credit card that has a public API?

Tags: api

I want to write my own app/tool for managing my finances, but I would rather not manually enter in every single transaction I make with my credit card or bank account.

Is there any bank or credit card provider that exists that has a public API for allowing you API access to your own transactions? All I want to see is each expenditure / deposit, the description, the amount, and the date.

I'd happily switch to any company that provided this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a large amount of Googling, and reading different articles and forums, I finally found https://plaid.com/ .

I haven't had a chance to explore all of their features / limitations yet, but as far as I can tell so far, they fit my use case perfectly: You can give them your bank or credit card login credentials, and they give you an access token for their API and allow you to access transaction data from your account.

Answer (score 0):

This old closed for "being OT" question on SO may be of interest -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis

I know with my Fidelity account I can export a CSV file (medical providers too, makes great time savings when doing income taxes) with transaction history/data in a parseable format, and my credit union has similar as well as export to QuickBooks, etc.

If you can't find an API for what you want, you may be able to play with exporting a login cookie and using `curl` or similar to act like a browser to download/export in some supported format.

You may also want to put a location (at least country), since a local to me in a small town in Florida credit union probably won't be much useful info if you are out of that local area.